# Hibernate associations Vs Hibernate property

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I did some level reading but couldn't able to find out proper answer, that is why this theory question:

I have a case where, there are lot of many-one mappings across data model (with default fetch strategy). As data grows (with few thousand records), retrieval performance is very bad. When I look at generated queries I have observed that lot of `Joins`.

Part of fine tuning process, I am trying to remove/modify un-necessary associations, starting with bi-directional.

**My question is:** *Do we need associations at all (could be one-may/many-many) if we don't need navigational comfort. What may be an issue if we simply remove association in hbm file and make it is as non-null property.*

Example: (Just for understanding purpose, this is not real case).

```
<class name="Book" table="BOOK">
        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="Name" length="50" not-null="true" />
        </property>
</class>

<class name="Shelf" table="SHELF">
        <property name="code" type="string">
            <column name="CODE" length="50" not-null="true" />
        </property>
       <one-to-many class="Book" column="bookId" />
</class>
```

If I change `Shelf` like below, would I be breaking any data modeling principles?

```
 <class name="Shelf" table="SHELF">
        <property name="code" type="string">
            <column name="CODE" length="50" not-null="true" />
        </property>
       <property column="bookId" not-null="true"/>
 </class>
```

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: In your example `bookId` is not a Ont-To-Many relationship anymore and cannot store multiple BookId values. Did you considered simply setting the FetchType to Lazy?

Comment: @AndreiI: Yes, that is exactly my question is. Am I violating any data /relational model principles by removing that association? Lazy/select fetch would be my final option.

Comment: lazy fetching IS the appropriate option. The field IS an association, and you don't want it to be loaded. That's what lazy fetching allows.

Comment: I don't think you're violating any data modelling principles by doing this. The data model remains the same. However, you will be violating object-oriented design principles, because instead of a `Shelf` having an association with a set of `Book`s, it simply has, what, an ID which you can use to fetch a set of books from some DAO somewhere? This has been done in a codebase i work on (largely for the same performance reasons), and it is painful; code complexity, lines of code, and the potential for bugs are all increased.

Comment: @JBNizet: I agree. It does help me in improving performance, but some places still it is slow. I need to identify those queries and dig deep. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That, what you made in your example, makes sense ONLY in rare cases (e.g we used it when we wanted to separate  2 modules, that had to remain unknown to each other, one module being reused in different projects).

On the other hand, the LAZY Fetch type is the way to go, because it is backward compatible with the current behavior (if you get  later some problems, you will simply revert the FetchType and the DB will not suffer any modifications) and you will still be able to navigate to other entities in future if you will need it. Besides this is how you model things in a POO language.

If you still have any performance problems with the FetchType.Lazy option, you should try to solve them instead (although I doubt you will get any performance improvements with your example).

PS: May be, there will be someone who will give a better answer, but I will try to answer the question.